# name of standard USB tip

Tags: usb, connector, sbc

I wonder what is the name of USB ports like this. I'm searching for SBC with this kind of port but I can't find nowhere what's name of tips like that:

[image]

Comment: By "tip" do you mean "connector"?

Comment: yes, i mean this white connector

Comment: What's the pitch? I'm guessing it's something made by JST since they make stuff that looks like that. It woudl also help if you showed us what the header looked like without the connector in it.

Comment: While this might be USB, it's really not standard.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Is there a standard? USB connections in PC motherboard side are just header pins from what I have seen; Especially the USB connections to the front panel of the CPU case.

Comment: I think the 2× 5 pin headers you see on motherboards are standard, as they all adhere to the same scheme. This isn't similar to that scheme.